# How to implement Google Tag Manager?

Tags: php, google

Trying to use google tag manager. It requires code in the . I tried editing the theme for our website but its returning a white screen see the below code before I add Tag Manager

```
    echo '<body class="'.implode (' ',get_body_class()).'">';
$body_top_scripts = get_theme_mod( 'scripts-at-beginning-of-body', '' );
if(trim($body_top_scripts) <>'') echo $body_top_scripts;
```

after....

```
    echo '<body <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=notgonnashowdis"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) --> class="'.implode (' ',get_body_class()).'">';
$body_top_scripts = get_theme_mod( 'scripts-at-beginning-of-body', '' );
if(trim($body_top_scripts) <>'') echo $body_top_scripts;
```

What can I try? I don't know what `( 'scripts-at-beginning-of-body', '' );` is tbh but it looks like something I should find.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my own issue with some research on the theme_mod()

Turns out it added a section to the customizer in WordPress and actually allows me to use custom JavaScript in the body.